# How to check if an ens name is valid or not

Tags: web3.py, python, ens, namehash

How can I check if an ENS domain name is correct or not? I would like to know how they are being calculated. I mean what are the standard rules.

Here is `web3.py` output.

```py
In [1]: from ens.utils import is_valid_ens_name

In [2]: is_valid_ens_name("-example.eth")
Out[2]: True

In [3]: is_valid_ens_name("-example.eth-")
Out[3]: True

In [4]: is_valid_ens_name("-example-.eth-")
Out[4]: True
```

Comment: The current standard is defined here: https://docs.ens.domains/ens-improvement-proposals/ensip-15-normalization-standard